# How to Define a Function in Python Which Its Name Contain a Variable?

Tags: python, function

Working with Python 2.7, How can i define a function which it's name has a variable? like:

```
for x in xrange(40):
  def functionname + x():
    print x
```

?

Comment: I tried to do this once, it can be done, but really *shouldn't be done.*  Your best bet is trying to find a way around.  Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @wnnmaw Will i have to define almost 40 function for a program that i make, i really don't want to create them manually.

Comment: Why 40 different functions? Why not 1 function which can handle all 40 cases?  If you can go a little more in-depth about the specifics of what you're attempting, I'm sure an alternative can be found

Comment: Sounds like [your data is mingling with your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: If you have to do this, store references to the functions in a list or dictionary.

Comment: @mhs: if you have 40 times the same function then it's a design smell. Improve your design instead.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

This is how it works. Glad I could help.

```
for x in xrange(40):
    
    exec('def functionname' + str(x) + '(): print ' + str(x))

exec('functionname' + str(2) + '()')
exec('functionname' + str(5) + '()')
```

EDIT: This is not a good style though. Maybe you should try to solve it in another way. Yes, better look at kindalls answer. Sorry.

Comment: I highly recommend other folks looking at this question do *not* do it this way. Use [kindall's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25044696/2073595) instead, if you absolutely have to generate separate functions.

Comment: I agree with dano, this is absolutely not a good idea. What the OP is trying to do is not even a smart idea in the first place.

Comment: I think you are both right. This is not a good style.

Comment: For anyone reading this: **DONT** do this. Just dont. Really.

Comment: Self-vandalism rolled back. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209436/self-vandalism-what-is-correct-action

Answer (score 7):

Store references to the functions in a list or dictionary.

To do this, let's make a function that makes the function which we will store in our list:

```
def functionmaker(x):
    def function():
        print(x)
    return function
```

This allows us to capture the value `x` at the time of the function's creation.

Now let's make a list of such functions:

```
functionlist = [functionmaker(x) for x in xrange(40)]
```

Now we can call them:

```
functionlist[5]()    # prints 5
```

Answer (score 4):

This is *insane*.

Why not do:

```
def functionname(x):
    if x > 40:
        raise ValueError
```

And then handle each case however you please.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more Pythonic way than relying on exec(), is using the locals() dict.

```
from __future__ import print_function

for x in range(40):
    funcname = "functionname" + str(x)
    function = lambda x=x: print(x)
    locals()[funcname] = function
```

These lines were written by trained professionals. Don't try this at home... or do, it's just bad programming practice.

Two notes:

- The `print_function` import makes it possible to print in `lambda`s
- `lambda x=x:` is a workaround for [one of Python's gotchas](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures).